# Android replaceAll() removes wrong chars from String

Tags: java, android, regex

My 'replaceAll()' method removes wrong chars from string. Below the the String

```
String i = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15"
```

if I want to remove '2,' from i its removes the '2,' from 12 also. so the new string is now;

```
String i = "1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,113,14,15"
```

here is the current code that I'm using:

```
String filter = temp.replaceAll(itemClicked + ",","");
```

how can i correct this?

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I suppose regexp would be better - but if you want to keep it very simple temp.replaceAll("," + itemClicked + ",", ",") should prevent removing "2" from "12". Edit.. Exept this does not work for first and last values on the string...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider using word boundaries `\b` here.

```
String filter = s.replaceAll("(?:\\b" + itemClicked + "\\b,|,\\b" + itemClicked + "$)", "");
```

Comment: Note that you are removing both the commas with that.

Comment: You're almost done, you need to fix the case when you remove the last element :)

Comment: Yeah, just need to remove the last comma when removing the last element, then it'll work.

Comment: `String filter = temp.replaceAll("\\b" + itemClicked + "\\b,?|,?\\b" + itemClicked + "$", "");` will fix your trailing comma problem.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any context around what you're doing? Is there a reason that you're storing a comma delimited String with numbers, rather than, say, an Array or List of numbers? If you used one of those, the removal would be much simpler. But again, I don't know the context of what you're doing.

Comment: +1 Depending on the context, using a `List` would be a better idea.

Comment: yea to be honest this is a small defect affecting quite a large project so i cannot afford to change that

Comment: I guess you could always split the string on "," and then remove the element you want from the resulting array, and then rebuild the comma delimited String. A little bit expensive and annoying, but I'm not very good at regex :). Depending on what libraries you have at your disposal, the recreating of the comma delimited String from the Array could be done with StringUtils.join. If not, it's simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String filter = temp.replaceAll("(^" + itemClicked + ",)|(," + itemClicked + "$)", "").replace("," + itemClicked + ",", ",");
```

Comment: for "3" you get `1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,114,15`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the issue is that you aren't catching the surroundings of the number in question. To do this, you'll need to take into account three possibilities:

1. The number begins the list "3,2.."
2. The number is in the middle of the list "..,3,4,..."
3. The number is at the end of the list "..,14,3"

So you'll need to split this into two or three pieces of logic as each has to be reacted to differently. With possibility #2, we catch both the comma before and after and will need to leave one comma behind. With possibilities #1 and #3 we're catching either the start or the end of the string and thus will leave nothing behind. So we can pare down the logic to two filters:

```
String regexOne = "," + itemClicked + ",";
String regexTwo = "($" + itemClicked + ",|" + itemClicked + "$)";
String filter = temp.replaceAll(regexOne, ","); // Catches #2
filter = filter.replaceAll(regexTwo, ""); // Catches #1 & #3
```

Because we are forced to take two different actions we can't reduce it down any further than those two steps.

To follow up with your example, let's assume the following:

```
String i = "3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11,13,311,3";
```

Applying the new code will catch the 3 in the middle with the first filter ",3," and replace it with ",", and both the "3," and the ",3" at the beginning and ending cleanly, leaving you with a final string of "1,2,4,5,6,7,11,13,311".